# Converting SQL Server connection to Oracle database connection (ASP.NET Core MVC & C#)

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g, asp.net-core-mvc

I need a little help here. I'm trying to modify my functions in order to make them work in an Oracle database, I need to be able to get my **Get** and **Create** methods working on my Oracle database.

This is my create method:

```
public void CreateRow(Person person)
{
    using SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InserNewRow", con);
                         {
                              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                         }

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", person.CODE);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", person.NAME);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", person.LASTNAME);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

This is my get method:

```
public IEnumerable<Person>GetPersonList
{
    var listPerson = new List<Person>;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from myview", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
             var person = new Person();
             person.CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString());
             person.NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString();
             person.LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString();

             listPerson.Add(person);
        }

        con.Close();
   }

   return listPerson;
}
```

Now, I am trying to connect the above methods to an Oracle database.

I added this:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client 
using Oracle.DataAccess
```

Changed my string connection to this:

```
"DATA SOURCE=10.204.3.1:1521/PROD;" + "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=username; password=password; Pooling =False;"
```

I started modifying the Get method:

```
public IEnumerable<Person>GetPersonList
{
    var listPerson = new List<Person>();

    using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString2))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from myview", con);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = 1000;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var list = new listPerson();
        list.CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString());
        list.NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString();
        list.LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString();

        listPerson.Add(list);
    }

    con.Close();
}
return listPerson;
```

I am kinda lost, can help me to modify my methods?

**EDIT**:

```
readonly string connectionString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxxxxxx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PROD)));User Id=xxx;Password=xxxx;"

public IEnumerable<Person>GetPersonList
        {
            var listPerson = new List<Person>();

            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from myview", con);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = 1000;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read()){
                var list = new Person();
                    list.CODE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CODE"].ToString());
                    list.NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString();
                    list.LASTNAME = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString();

                    listPerson.Add(list);
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return listPerson;
        }
```

Comment: Why did you remove the connection opening and the whole datareader stuff?

Comment: And the _select * from myview_ is not a stored procedure. You should remove the line that sets the commandtype and let the default stay (commandtype.Text)

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't need both `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` and `Oracle.DataAccess`. I would suggest you only need the first one. Second, check your Oracle connection string matches this: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/. Thirdly, you'll need to have a `tnsnames.ora` file in the executable directory or, preferably, add a `<dataSource>` to your app settings file. And lastly, your revised code doesn't instantiate or open a `OracleDataReader` object; how were you intending to read the data?

Comment: Hey @Steve how am i supposed to retrieve all that Data coming from a view?

Comment: @WSC i have edited my question, is that okay? am i missing anything?

Comment: @Steve i have edited my question, take a look: is that okay?

Comment: That code seems to be ok. Do you have some errors? If yes what message do you get?

Comment: Steve, take a look at my connectionString. Is that okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My EDIT worked just fine. Thank you Steve :)